# Getting contents of system clipboard on headless linux server for automated testing

Tags: awt, clipboard, copy-paste, headless, xvfb

I am trying to run some selenium cases on a headless linux system through docker in which the "user" clicks a button that copys text to the system clipboard. When I run this code, I get an error that says "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it."
I am now running the case using xvfb to account for the lack of X11 Display variable, but the code still does not work. Now, I am getting a nullpointer when trying to access the contents of the system clipboard.

Here is the code that I am running to get the copied text.

```
String copied = null;

    try {

        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        Transferable transferable = clipboard.getContents(null);
        DataFlavor[] availableFlavors = clipboard.getAvailableDataFlavors();

        if ( transferable != null && transferable.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor) ) {
            copied = (String)transferable.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Could not find a suitable flavor.");
            if ( transferable.getTransferDataFlavors().length == 0 ) {
                System.out.println("no supported flavors");
            }
            for ( DataFlavor availableFlav : availableFlavors ) {
                System.out.println("availableFlav = " + availableFlav);
            }
            for ( DataFlavor flavaflav : transferable.getTransferDataFlavors() ) {
                System.out.println("transferDataFlavor = " + flavaflav);
            }
        }

    // I am not sure what could cause the below exceptions to happen, but we should just fail the case if they occur.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail("IOException while fetching copied text.");
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail("UnsupportedFlavorException while fetching copied text.");
    }

    return copied;
```

Running this code with xvfb is resulting in the following output:

```
Could not find a suitable flavor.
no supported flavors
```

And then throws the NullPointerException.

Is there a way to fake a system clipboard that actually works in this headless linux server?
What might be causing the system clipboard running in xvfb to have nothing copied?